# Issue loading iframe url in angular

Tags: html, angular, web, iframe

I have an angular application where in a particular component I am trying to iframe a url.

The iframe url is added in the html page of component with tag:-
`<iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>`

Added Content-Security-Policy for iframe url in index.html with below tag:-

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src 'self' https://www.google.com data: blob:">
```

The box on webpage says "This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue".
On browser console it shows below error:
Refused to frame 'https://www.google.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src data: blob:".

Also, I tried adding the Content-Security-Policy in angular.json with below code. It still throws the same error.

```
"headers":{
            "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only": "frame-src 'self' https://www.google.com data: blob:"
          }
```

Please help to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Websites can have response headers that let the browser know if they can be rendered in an `iframe`

Looking at the response headers when loading `google.com` I can see:

```
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Stackoverflow also prevents rendering in an iframe where the host is anything other than `self` (stackoverflow origin) or `https://stackexchange.com`

```
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. What you are saying makes perfect sense and my bad that I tried www.google.com for testing. Actually, I have to integrate one internal url with my angular app where the response header is not set to SAMEORIGIN, but that also throws same error.  The url which I am trying to iframe has nginx reverse proxy set in front of the web server, do I need to place some CSP in nginx.conf file with "add_header Content-Security-Policy *****". If you could suggest something that would be of great help.